# Python OpenCV cv2 drawing rectangle with text

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I draw a rectangle on my image using

```
cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x1,y1),(0,255,0),2)
```

I would like to draw rectangles with text information on them. How do I do it? Are there any ready to use implementations available? Or should I match the top left coordinate of the rectangle and try to display a different cv2 text element with the cv2 rect element?

Can you direct me to any code implementation/workaround?

P.S: I don't want to use the object_detection. visualisation utils available with tf.

[image]

Comment: You should *match the top left coordinate of the rectangle and try to display a different cv2 text element with the cv2 rect element*

Comment: Do you mean to say there is no ready-made implementation in OpenCV? Can you direct me to any workaround?

Comment: There is none as far as I know. Just taking the upper left edge coordinate is quite trivial though and you should be able to do that.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can use [`cv2.putText()`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#void%20putText(Mat&%20img,%20const%20string&%20text,%20Point%20org,%20int%20fontFace,%20double%20fontScale,%20Scalar%20color,%20int%20thickness,%20int%20lineType,%20bool%20bottomLeftOrigin)) to overlay text information on top of a rectangle. For example, you can grab the contour coordinates, draw a rectangle, and put text on top of it by shifting it upwards.

```
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
image = cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 1)
cv2.putText(image, 'Fedex', (x, y-10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.9, (36,255,12), 2)
```

You will get something like this

[image]

Comment: Really helped a lot. Thanks for great answer.

Answer (score 14):

[image]

Maybe too late for you but we could do something like this:

x1, y1 is top left point
x2, y2 is bottom right point

```py
# For bounding box
img = cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), color, 2)
 
# For the text background
# Finds space required by the text so that we can put a background with that amount of width.
(w, h), _ = cv2.getTextSize(
        label, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.6, 1)

# Prints the text.    
img = cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y1 - 20), (x1 + w, y1), color, -1)
img = cv2.putText(img, label, (x1, y1 - 5),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.6, text_color, 1)

# For printing text
img = cv2.putText(img, 'test', (x1, y1),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.6, (255,255,255), 1)
```

Answer (score 8):

You may need to extend your code with a function that takes your text as `input`, `position_x`, `position_y` ... and it will measure the size of the letters and dynamically set a rectangle width based on that.

You can use

`cv2.getTextSize(text, font, font_scale, thickness)`

to get how many pixels it will use and then use it to define the rectangle width.